# How to setup Hybris Eclipse for Development? when importing from a GIT

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

My source code for Hybris (custom extensions) are in a GIT Repository but my Hybris platform binaries are in another folder. (I am a newbie to hybris)

How to set my build path in this case?

Say if my custom extension folders are under (TFS Git Repository)
C:\HybrisCommerce

Whereas my Platform binaries
C:\HybrisBinary\Bin\Platform
C:\HybrisBinary\Config
C:\HybrisBinary\data\
C:\HybrisBinary\log\

How to configure Build Path in such a case?

Comment: Why don't you create your git repository in `C:\HybrisBinary\bin\custom` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Windows symlink to link your custom extensions folder to your hybris project folder. 
Here is an example. I am not sure if it will work exactly for your system so you may have to modify it.

```
mklink /J "C:\HybrisCommerce" "C:\HybrisBinary\Bin\custom"
```

This way, the default hybris build will search for its extension in bin/custom, which will actually point to you git repository.

For eclipse, you can just add all the projects into the workspace.  `General > Existing Project into Workspace` First all project from you hybris folder and after that all your custom projects from the git repository folder. **Important! Keep in mind, that eclipse will change the .project file of your custom extensions. Don't commit this file to git repository, because you might break the other team members projects.**

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create `symbolic link` as suggested by *@Hristo Staykov*

**Or**

Modify `localextenstion.xml` as below, to target all your `custom extenstions` (Taken from GIT/SVN) by giving full path (`dir`).

e.g. `<extension dir='C:\HybrisCommerce\custmocore' />`

Then configure your Eclipse for hybris e-commerce using [these steps](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/hybrisALF/SAP+Hybris+Commerce+development+tools+for+Eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Local Hybris setup,reach this location:

```
 [LOCAL_Path]\hybris\config\
```

Open the localextensions.xml,you will see something like this in the file:

```
<path dir='[PUT_YOUR_CUSTOM_LOCATION_PATH HERE]' autoload='false' />
```

Then add all the extension name(that needs to be included from custom/default here) right below it:

```
<extension name='abc' />
<extension name='xyz' />
<extension name='efg' />
```

Save it and Run ant clean all.